# Xcode finishes running immediately after duplicating project

Tags: macos, xcode5

I had a (Mac OS X) project which was building and running well with no problem. I duplicated the project. Now, the new duplicate project runs successfully, but finishes running immediately. If I try to run the app which is in the build folder of the new project, it asks me to sign in and download from app store!
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: When you say "but finishes running immediately", do you mean it crashes?

Comment: Xcode starts running the project and after a second it says finished running, and the app never launches. No error or anything.

Comment: All sounds a bit broken to me.  Why not just dump the duplicate (it's not even clear *why* you duplicated the project) and continue with the original.

Comment: I actually wanted to keep most of the old project, and make changes to the new one, to create new results that I need. I can definitely just create a new project and copy what I want manually. But, my question is, why the new project should be broken in the first place? I have experienced the same problem after duplicating other projects too. For example, if I am making games, I may be in a situation where I need an identical game engine which I write and use in several games. So I should be able to duplicate the project and build the new game and keep the game engine part of the old project.

Comment: Use git.  Create a branch.  When you've finished go back to the old branch.  Duplicating files like this is clumsy and error prone and tedious.

Comment: OK, I will try that. Sounds like there is no easy way of doing what I want in Xcode, thanks anyway.